Do I need service mesh to secure my k8s cluster communication
Many articles across the internet recommend using service mesh solutions like Istio or Linkerd to secure network communication inside a Kubernetes cluster. At the same time, popular CNI plugins like Calico or Cilium support traffic encryption with WireGuard or IPSEC.
This can be a bit confusing, so I have a couple of questions:
If I don’t need any service mesh features other than security, will there be any security-related issues if I only enable CNI-level encryption compared to using a service mesh?
Is there any research on the performance cost of encryption between CNI encryption and service mesh mTLS? My intuition is that CNI-level encryption should be faster, but is there any empirical data to support this?
